# How to remove unnecessary zero's behind the decimal in a column

Tags: r

In my dataframe I have a column as follows:

> 25,000
>
> 35,000
>
> 65,000
>
> 8,125
>
> 12,000

In this column I want to remove the unnecessary zero's.

So that it looks like this:

> 25
>
> 35
>
> 65
>
> 8,125
>
> 12

The data is from a CSV file with 50K rows and nine columns total, three of which I want to remove the zero's from.
I have tried things like `sub` and `round` but so far I've had no luck

Is it possible to write a piece of code that removes the unnecessary zero's from the whole column?

**Solution:**

`df$your_col <- sub(',000', '', your_col)`

Comment: Do you want to remove the zeroes from the _data itself_ or from the _visualization_ of the data? What is the data type (e.g., integer, double, character, ...)?

Comment: Try `sub(',000', '', your_col)` but the `,` in `8,125` prevents you from turning to numeric

Comment: @Sotos That is not necessarily true with e.g. some European locales.

Comment: @Roman I had no idea about that, but I know there is also an option in `options` about the decimal. However I think that is not the case here and coercing to `numeric` will result to NAs

Comment: Im gonna try out some of your codes! thanks

Comment: @ Michiel, which class should be the columns you need to transform?

Comment: @Sotos This seems to be working! I changed the ```,``` to ```.``` so now i dont get any errors! thanks!

Comment: @Sotos Do you by any chance know how to also remove the zeroes from things like ```12,400``` and ```17,780```.  I tried it with ```sub(',x00)``` but that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Maybe something like `gsub(',0|0', '', your_col)`